# Rails Step-by-Step object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I wonder what's the best way to design an object creation step by step.

For example,

I have a model **order** and I want too design the **order/new** such that, by clicling on **create new order** user goes over the following steps:

1. fills all user related information, press **Continue**
2. fills content product information, press **Continue**
3. fills some other information....press **Continue**

The problem is ut is a difficult design to create, I've never saw the example of such design ni source code, however it's very popular step-by-step creation.

The difficulty is all filled information relates to **order** and by pressing continue I should to save the info somewhere then open new form, fill the info there and save and at the end create object **order**.

Do you familiar with the described scenario, and how to implement it in rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [Wicket](https://github.com/schneems/wicked).

https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step

What your describing are called Wizard forms:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast

In the tutorial you can manage forms in separate steps:

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**

[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) does.

[Here is a Railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?language=fr&view=asciicast)